# Definition of restriction of morphism of ringed space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ringed-spaces

I have a question. Is there a definition of restriction of morphism of (locally) ringed space?

Let $(f,f^{\flat}): X \to Y$ bea morphism of ringed spaces ; i.e., $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map and $f^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$  is a homomorphism of sheaves of rings on $Y$.

Now, let $U \subseteq Y$ be an open set and consider the restriction $f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)} : f^{-1}(U) \to U$. Then can we consider a morphism of sheaves $(f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)})^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_U \to (f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)})_{*}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U)}$ ? ; i.e., is there a natural definition for $(f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)})^{\flat}$?

Perhaps, for each open $V\subseteq U$, $(f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)})^{\flat}_V := f^{\flat}_{V}$ ?

(It seems that it will be good if $\iota^{*}(f^{\flat})= (f|^{U}_{f^{-1}(U)})^{\flat}$, where $\iota : U \hookrightarrow Y $ is the inclusion and $\iota^{*}$ is the inverse image functor.)

Comment: What you guess is correct, since being a homomorphism of sheaves (or a natural transformation of functors), it encapsulates a lot of data: effects on all open subsets are included.

Comment: Yes. Thank you ~~